# How to create tensorflow RaggedTensor from python list?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ragged

I have two-dimensional list (list of lists). I would like to create RaggedTensor from it.

But here is no method to create RaggedTensor from python list.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple:

```
tf.ragged.constant(list)
```